# Why does setInterval call my function once?

Tags: javascript

```
function start (argument){
    alert("Starting Quiz!");
    var time = setInterval( timer(), 1000);

}

function timer(){
    console.log("Time: " + counter + " seconds");
}
```

I found that when setInterval( "timer()", 1000); works as intended repeatably calling my timer function, but when I don't use quotes "" the function is only called once. Why is that?

Comment: call it without the `()` like this: `setInterval(timer, 1000)`

Comment: Instead of passing the function as an argument you are just executing it once.

Comment: The first parameter of `setInterval` wants to know *"Which function do you want to call?"*. However, instead of giving it the name of said function (`timer`), you've *executed* the function by including parentheses. Just change `timer()` to `timer`.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the function yourself. You should just pass the function:

```
var time = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

When you passed a string, you were telling it to evaluate an expression in the global context.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense, but could you perhaps expand on the global context part?

Comment: @CodyIg0R44Roe: passing a string is the same as passing `new Function("...")`. Functions created this way are defined in global scope.